# Авторизация на pythone

Tags: python, requests, авторизация

Добрый день!
  С помощью библиотеки requests посылаю запрос на авторизацию
в ответ получаю, что все Ок, хотя ввожу ерунду.

```
r = requests.get('http://www.facebook.com',auth=('blah','blahblah'))
r.status_code выдает 200
```

Comment: Так как фейсбуку наплевать, есть или нет в запросе http basic auth, он и отдает вам абсолютно спокойно главную страницу.

Я уж молчу о том, что страница может любой статус вернуть, это ничего не говорит о том, что было проделано.

Вы бы разобрались сначала, что код делает.

Comment: @Etki а как сделать, то что я хочу?

Comment: не нужно ровняться на код состояния http от фейсбука, т.к. фейсбук практически всегда отдает 200й

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы делаете называется HTTP Basic Auth, никакого отношения к логину на FB оно не имеет.
Вы просто запросили у него страницу логина и он вам ее отдал со статусом 200 OK.